# Flatten list of negative numbers

Tags: list, null, tcl, flatten

I am trying to flatten the following type of Tcl lists:

```
-1587.500000 {} 1587.500000
```

or

```
15.78 18.56 {} {} {} {} 15.6
```

So I try:

```
 [struct::list flatten -full $lineToFlatten]
```

But when `lineToFlatten` starts with the negative number the following type of error message is issued (for example):

```
  Unknown option "-1587.500000 {} 1587.500000", should be either -full, or --
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: I don't know that command (`struct::list`), but try using this instead: `[struct::list flatten -full -- $lineToFlatten]`

Comment: [Jerry](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1578604/jerry) Now the error message is the following: wrong#args: should be "::struct::list::Lflatten ?-full? ?--? sequence"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, the correct way is to use the `--` to denote the end of the options. But there is a bug that prevents you from doing that (missing `lrange`).

The correct way to do that is:

```
struct::list flatten -full -- {-1587.500000 {} 1587.500000}
```

But this does not work because `struct` has a bug.

If you want to fix it, open the package file for `struct::list`, you can get the filename with

```
package ifneeded struct::list [package require struct::list]
```

Then edit the proc `::struct::list::Lflatten`.
Change the line with

```
--      {break}
```

to

```
--      {set args [::lrange $args 1 end];break}
```

Anyway, I suggest filling a bug record.

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered how to use this function ^^

Okay, I can't say why it acts like this, but it throws me an error for anything like:

```
[struct::list flatten -full $lineToFlatten]

[struct::list flatten -full {-1587.500000 {} 1587.500000}]
```

It seems that it interprets the negative sign as a switch/flag instead of an element of the list. However, it works if I do:

```
[struct::list flatten -full {{-1587.500000} {} 1587.500000}]

[struct::list flatten -full [list $lineToFlatten]]
```

The first one isn't very practical, since you'll have a long command and you have to put the braces manually for the first negative number. I found the second workaround while testing a bit around.

I hope it helps :)